# Find/replace string with carriage return and line feed in PowerShell

Tags: powershell, control-characters

Is there a way to have PowerShell find and replace a string (for example **~}}|{{E**) with a carriage return and line feed (**\r\nE**)?

For example:

```
$filenames = @("E:\blergfest.csv")
foreach ($file in $filenames) {
    $outfile = "$file" + ".out"

    Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
        $_ -replace '\~}}|{{E', '\r\nE' `
            -replace '\|\r\n', '\r\n'
    } | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How about this:

```
$filenames = @("E:\blergfest.csv")
foreach ($file in $filenames) {
    $outfile = "$file" + ".out"

    Get-Content $file | Foreach-object {
        $_ -replace '\~}}|{{E', "`r`nE" `
            -replace '\|\r\n', "`r`n"
    } | Set-Content $outfile
}
```

Comment: Would it be too much to ask for you to have a statement like "in your replacement text, use the backtick `\`` instead of a backslash ``\``, like below:" (?)

Answer (score 3):

To create a string that contains the control characters with carriage return and line feed, you would use double quotes and use the backtick character ` which is the powershell escape code. Like this:

```
"`r`nE"
```